# LESS import issue

Tags: css, less

Trying out a simple one, three less files:

colors.less:

```
@green:green;
```

background.less

```
body {
   background-color: @green;
}
```

main.less

```
@import: "colors.less";
@import: "background.less";
```

When I

```
 lessc main.less main.css
```

Nothing is in output. I thought when you import less files, it will get resolved. Double-checked with how twitter bootstrap is doing it...it seems to work fine for them.
I am using lessc 1.3.3 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript] as LESS compiler

Answer (score 3):

the colon turns it into a variable declaration. remove the colon.

```
@import "file.less";
```

Comment: Luke is correct, I didn't even notice the colons at all - they slipped right by me. This is the answer that should be selected

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you gave, make sure all of the files are in the same folder. Otherwise it won't work unless you either:

- change the paths in the `@import` statements to point to the location of the files, or
- use a compiler such as [assemble-less](http://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) to define the path(s) the the imported files